# Singleton-pattern destroyable by inner class?

Tags: java, security, singleton, inner-classes

I wrote a class following the Singleton-pattern and would like to write a inner class for it next.
What worries me is that the inner class is able to access all of the outer classes private fields, including the private field for the single instance and i suppose the private constructor likewise.

Is it possible to attack the singleton and to make a second instance of it when one has access to the constructor of the inner class?

I was thinking of some kind of navigating from an instance of the inner class to the constructor of the class.
So for example:

```
class Outer{

    private static Outer instance;
    private Outer(){}
    public static Outer getInstance(){
    if(instance==null)instance= new Outer();
    return instance;
    }

    class Inner{
    public Inner(){}

}
```

and now something like:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[]args){
    Outer outer = Outer.getInstance();
    Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
    Outer outer2 = inner.Outer.this.new Outer();
    }

}
```

Noticing that the last line is not compilable I thought there might be some other way to "navigate" to the constructor of the outer class once one has an object of the inner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What worries me is that the inner class is able to access all of the
>   outer classes private fields, including the private field for the
>   single instance and i suppose the private constructor likewise.

That's the whole purpose in life of inner class, read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), inner classes are meant for the situation when you want to keep some state of a class as private but still want a cohesive class to access it, so in those situation you make an inner class for that top level class.

> Is it possible to attack the singleton and to make a second instance
>   of it when one has access to the constructor of the inner class?

If you have implemented proper singleton pattern for your top level class then no-one can create another instance of your top level class.

Also, just in case if you are thinking otherwise then when you create an instance of inner class then it doesn't create an instance of outer class, no there again there are scenarios like if you have a static inner class then you do need an instance of top level class but if you have a non-static inner class then first you need to create a instance of top level class and then you create instance of your inner class, **but whole point is that creating an instance of inner class doesn't create another instance of outer class**, so if you have implemented singleton pattern properly in our outer class then you are fine.

I would recommend you to read about inner classes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

> Singleton-pattern destroyable by inner class?

With above explanation, answer is no, with a properly implemented singleton pattern in top level class, an inner of it cannot create another instance of the top level class.

Comment: A static _initialization_ block is equivalent to an eager initialization `private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();` only more verbose. The one-liner is better, but not as good as `public enum Foo { INSTANCE }`. You should change your preference to the enum approach.

Comment: @LewBloch Yes I agree with you and aware also, but that's the way I was do because of my own reasons, however I think those lines of mine may cause some confusion so I have removed those for best interests.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to indicate that you're trying to prevent an attacker from making specific changes in your source code. If someone has that level of access already, there's no security on Earth that can protect you from an attack.

Comment: Excuse me for using such a strong term like "attack". At this point it's more about the pure possibility to make the Singleton ineffective by the existence of inner classes.